# Cannot pass handler parameter to code. Newbie

Tags: applescript

Background: I am trying to pass caller information from a telephony application (Phone Amego) to my Samsung tv using its AllShare feature. In order to do so I have to send a soap message with the caller information. Phone Amego provides an easy way to assign an applescript to call events. But, I have no programming experience whatsoever!

Sofar I have succeeded in making a script which reads a soap message, updates the required fields and sends it to my tv. Perfect, at least the result, the code may not be perfect but it works. Here is the code.

```
set callerID_string to "John Doe : 1-917-123-4567"
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {":"}
set pieces to text items of callerID_string
set callerID_name to item 1 of pieces
set callerID_number to item 2 of pieces
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}

set myDate to do shell script "date '+%d.%m.%Y'"
set myTime to do shell script "date '+%T'"
set total_Length to (length of callerID_name) + (length of callerID_number) + 780
set search_strings to {"Content-Length: 796", "2013-01-01", "00:00:00", "Mike", "777-777-7777"}
set replace_strings to {"Content-Length:" & total_Length, myDate, myTime, callerID_name, callerID_number}

tell application "Finder"
set theFile to alias "Macintosh HD:Users:Marc:Desktop:IncCallMBsTemplate.txt"
open for access theFile
set fileRef to open for access (theFile as alias)
set fileContents to (read fileRef)
close access theFile
end tell

set the clipboard to fileContents

repeat with i from 1 to (count search_strings)
set the_string to the clipboard
set the_string to my snr(the_string, item i of search_strings, item i of replace_strings)
end repeat

on snr(the_string, search_string, replace_string)
tell (a reference to my text item delimiters)
    set {old_atid, contents} to {contents, search_string}
    set {the_string, contents} to {the_string's text items, replace_string}
    set {the_string, contents} to {"" & the_string, old_atid}
end tell
set the clipboard to the_string


-- Create a file handler for the file to write to.

set myFile to (open for access alias "Macintosh HD:Users:Marc:Desktop:Test.txt" with write permission)
try
    -- Delete current contents of the file
    set eof myFile to 0
    -- Write to file
    write the_string to myFile as «class utf8»
end try
-- Close the file
close access myFile
end snr

set cmd to "/Usr/bin/nc 10.0.1.7 52235 < /Users/Marc/Desktop/Test.txt"
do shell script cmd
```

Problem: In the script above I have set a value to the variable callerID_string, but I should obtain it from Phone Amego through the handler call_from(callerID_string). But whatever I try, I cannot pass that callerID_string to my code. It consists of 2 parts namely the caller's name and number. The code should start like:

```
on call_from(callerID_string)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your script is running with the other app at the same time and it needs that handler and therefore a little re-designing so we can call the (former main) code as a subroutine.

I'm not sure if I understood the situation correctly but here it is anyway:

I added the on `call_from...` handler which calls the rest of the code as subroutine (`myAction`).

First commented line in code can be uncommented and used to test-run it with `AppleScript Editor`. Remove the line when not needed anymore.

`testFilePath` is a property and globally visible. Also, I changed the hardcoded file-path-stuff so it finds the path to the desktop.

```
property testFilePath : ""


-- my myAction("John Doe : 1-917-123-4567")


on call_from(callerID_string)

    my myAction(callerID_string)

end call_from


on myAction(CIS)

    if CIS is "" then
        tell me to activate
        display dialog "Caller ID is empty." buttons {"Quit"} default button 1 with icon 0
        return
    end if

    set pathToDesktop to (path to desktop) as text
    set testFilePath to pathToDesktop & "Test.txt"

    set callerID_string to CIS -- "John Doe : 1-917-123-4567"

    set lastTextItemDelimeter to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {" : "}

    set pieces to text items of callerID_string
    set callerID_name to item 1 of pieces
    set callerID_number to item 2 of pieces

    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""} -- or lastTextItemDelimeter if you want to change it back to last

    set myDate to do shell script "date '+%d.%m.%Y'"
    set myTime to do shell script "date '+%T'"
    set total_Length to (length of callerID_name) + (length of callerID_number) + 780
    set search_strings to {"Content-Length: 796", "2013-01-01", "00:00:00", "Mike", "777-777-7777"}
    set replace_strings to {"Content-Length:" & total_Length, myDate, myTime, callerID_name, callerID_number}

    set templateFile to pathToDesktop & "IncCallMBsTemplate.txt"

    tell application "Finder"
        set theFile to templateFile as alias -- Macintosh HD:Users:Marc:Desktop:IncCallMBsTemplate.txt"
        open for access theFile
        set fileRef to open for access (theFile as alias)
        set fileContents to (read fileRef)
        close access theFile
    end tell

    set the clipboard to fileContents

    repeat with i from 1 to (count search_strings)
        set the_string to the clipboard
        set the_string to my snr(the_string, item i of search_strings, item i of replace_strings)
    end repeat

    set cmd to "/usr/bin/nc 10.0.1.7 52235 < " & quoted form of (POSIX path of testFilePath)
    do shell script cmd

end myAction

on snr(the_string, search_string, replace_string)

    tell (a reference to my text item delimiters)
        set {old_atid, contents} to {contents, search_string}
        set {the_string, contents} to {the_string's text items, replace_string}
        set {the_string, contents} to {"" & the_string, old_atid}
    end tell


    set the clipboard to the_string

    -- Create a file handler for the file to write to.
    set myFile to (open for access (testFilePath as alias) with write permission)

    try
        -- Delete current contents of the file
        set eof myFile to 0
        -- Write to file
        write the_string to myFile as «class utf8»
    on error the error_message number the error_number
        -- display dialog "Error: " & the error_number & ". " & the error_message buttons {"Cancel"} default button 1
        log "Error: " & the error_number & ". " & the error_message
    end try

    -- Close the file
    close access myFile
end snr
```

Comment: Your welcome! Thanks for the feedback. Please note that it is common to accept an answer if it solved the question.

Comment: Sorry, did not know that.Done in the meantime. I am a newbie here as well. Kind regards. Marc